# ssh uses wrong home directory in Cygwin

Tags: ssh, cygwin

```
$ ssh usaname@login.somehost.no

Could not create directory'/cygdrive/c/Documents and Settings/vidar kongsli/.ssh'.
The authenticity of host 'login.somehost.no (...)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is ....
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? no
Host key verification failed.

$ set | grep HOME

HOME=/cygdrive/d/home/vidar
HOMEDRIVE=C:
HOMEPATH=/cygdrive/d/home/vidar

$ ls ~/.ssh

id_rsa  id_rsa.pub
```

Any idea why ssh does not use the $HOME environment variable when it tries to locate ~/.ssh?

(edit: fixed formatting)

Answer (score 9):

Have a look at `/etc/passwd`.  Make sure the entry there matches your expected home directory.  It's the second to last field for your user's entry.

Answer (score 6):

If your `$HOME` variable is set, but ssh isn't recognizing it, put this line in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`:

```
db_home: /%H
```

That will set the Cygwin home directory without requiring an /etc/passwd file to exist.

Comment: I've set `HOME` to `%USERPROFIEL%` in environment variables before the cygwin installed. So... /home/<myusername> haven't be created (`/etc/passwd cannot be found`). And cannot using ssh key in %USERPROFILE%. `db_home: /%H` fix the issue perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

In /etc/nsswitch.conf:

```
db_home:  windows
```

See [The db_home setting](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/ntsec.html#ntsec-mapping-nsswitch-home).  This tells Cygwin to just use the Windows `%USERPROFILE%` directory as the Cygwin $HOME.

This is necessary if, for example, you want to share the same SSH keys between git (GitHub Enterprise) and SSH to various local Unix/Linux systems.

Setting `%HOME%` at the OS level did not work (even though `$HOME` in bash correctly reflects the setting).

You can see from the original question that SSH is trying to update the Windows home directory, which in Vidar's older version of Windows is `C:\Documents and Settings\vidar kongsli`.  In current versions (7+, I think), the equivalent is `C:\Users\%USERNAME%` (or, if Windows is not installed on C:, `%SystemDrive%\Users\%USERNAME%`).

Comment: This was the 1st one I've tried, but it also did not work for me - SSH kept on trying /home/blablabla, which obviously was not mapped. So far, just the /%H has worked. And, considering the docs, your answer really should be totally functional.

Comment: Glad you got it working.  Since answering, I have updated to Windows 10 and have updated Cygwin.   So, currently, I can share SSH keys fine w/out anything in /etc/nsswitch.conf at all (the default, I think).   It's not always clear to me why one thing works vs another.   But my guess it that it's related to the versions of Windows, Cygwin and SSH.

Answer (score 1):

Set `db_home` in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` to the path to your home.  This is the method [recommended](https://sourceforge.net/p/msys2/tickets/111/?page=2) by MSYS2.

Adding a `HOME` environment variable also [works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2840909/3366962).

Git-for-Windows includes `env` in `db_home`, which should read your `HOME` bash variable, however, it is [unreliable](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/736#issuecomment-215123009).

Comment: Editing how? What did you set db_home to?

Comment: @AndrewSchulman To the directory I want as my home directory?

Comment: wow! This is lot of helpful information. Thanks for edit @go2null :)

Comment: This answer does not actually list what the "recommended" linked bug recommends. The linked bug says: `db_home: windows cygwin desc`

Comment: I tried the other answers, but this is the one that worked.

Answer (score 0):

Is the variable `HOME` exported? Try: `export HOME` then `ssh` again.